# Most Pythonic way to abort a cache decorator?

Tags: python, flask, decorator

Let's say I have a Flask app called server and I have the cached blueprint like the following, making use of the decorators in flask.ext.cache:

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, request, Response
from server import cache

some_blueprint = Blueprint('some_blueprint', __name__)

def make_cache_key(*args, **kwargs):
  return request.url

@some_blueprint.route('/')
@cache.cached(timeout = 3600, key_prefix = make_cache_key)
def foo():
  # do some stuff
  if some stuff succeeds:
    return something
  else:
    return "failed"
```

Now, suppose "do some stuff" is something which succeeds 99.9% of the time, in which case I want the decorator to cache the result, but fails 0.01% of the time, in which case I want the decorator to NOT cache the "failed" result.

What's the most Pythonic way to do this? Am I forced to abandon the beauty of decorators?

Comment: If your function is not pure (if I interpret "succeeds" correctly), perhaps caching is not the best thing to do (or you should cache the pure part only)? *Edit:* can you throw an exception instead of returning "failed"?

Comment: By "succeeds" I don't mean the function itself will throw an exception, but rather that the operation it is attempting (e.g. an URL fetch) may be prone to things like network failures. If the network fails, the function gracefully reports the failure, but I don't want this to be cached. When the fetch succeeds though, I do want it to be cached.

Comment: Obviously, I could write my own home-brewed caching logic inside the function, but I'm just wondering if there's a "Pythonic" way to maintain the cleanliness of using decorators to achieve this, and moreover, the awesomeness of flask.ext.cache which abstracts away the underlying cache system (redis, memcache, etc.)

Comment: I think throwing an exception would be the Pythonic thing to do, if the `cache()` decorator can pass it through (where does it come from, by the way? Is `server` one of your modules, or a library?). If you still want to get `failed` as a result (as opposed to catching an exception), you can write a wrapper function on top of the cached one.

Comment: Throwing an exception instead of returning "failed" might not be a good idea since it would cause the web server to hiccup. I want to actually return the "failed" to the client so that the client knows the operation failed and can retry after some period of time when it feels like.

Comment: Oh! I see, you mean create a separate function that is @cache.cached() and throws an exception, and encapsulate a call to the decorated function in a try/except block. That could work, I'll try. Thanks!

Comment: Well, in that case I guess you can add another decorator between `some_blueprint` and `cache.cached` that will transform the exception into `"failed"`.

Answer (score 2):

(rewriting my comments as an answer)

You can throw an exception in the `foo()` function, so that it will not be cached (most cache functions will pass an exception through, consult the documentation of yours) and catch it in a wrapper function to transform it to `"failed"`. This wrapper function may or may not be a decorator:

```
def exception_to_failed(func)
  def wrapper(*args, **kwds):
    try:
      res = func(*args, **kwds)
    except: # better catch only specific exceptions, of course
      return "failed"
    return res
  return wrapper

@some_blueprint.route('/')
@exception_to_failed
@cache.cached(timeout = 3600, key_prefix = make_cache_key)
def foo():
  # do some stuff
  if some stuff succeeds:
    return something
  else:
    raise Exception() # or just rely on "some stuff" raising it
```